# php define statement failing while moving php app from linux system to one running windows 7 with wamp

Tags: php, linux, wamp

I'm setting up a dev environment to work on a php site. 
i've copied all my source code onto a windows 7 box running wamp.

I'm trying to update all the paths to reflect the correct locations on my dev box. 
But I'm having probem with some of my define statements.  For example, I have the following code:

```
define ('DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'c:\wamp\www\myapplicationname\members\');
define ('DB_LOG', 'c:\wamp\www\myapplicationname\members\log\db');
define ('ERROR_LOG', 'c:\wamp\www\myapplicationname\members\log\errors');
```

When I try to run site site, I get the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   C:\wamp\www\myapplicationname\members\includes\init.php on line 39

Line 39 is the second define statement I listed above.  I can tell there's a problem because the syntax highlighting for the second line is not working.  It doesn't recognize the "define" statement.
If I change the first line to look like:

```
 define ('DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'c:\wamp\www\myapplicationname\members\\');
```

then the highlighting works again, but ofcourse, the path is wrong.

Can you tell me what I'm missing ?

**EDIT 1**

I've tried to change it to:

'define ('DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'c:\wamp\www\myapplicationname\members\'');

but then later in the code when we're appending to DOCUMENT_ROOT like so,

```
require_once DOCUMENT_ROOT.'\inc\exception.class.php';
```

i get the following error:

Warning: require_once(c:\wamp\www\myapplicationname\members'\inc\exception.class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream:

Comment: `\'` is escaping the end `'`

Comment: can you tell me how to get around that? I thought doubling up would fix it but it didn't.  thank you

Comment: Simply use unix-style directory separators `/wamp/www/myapplicationname/members`: it still works for Windows

Comment: Mark Baker - you want to add that as an answer?  i'll accept...

Answer (score 1):

SO code highlighting shows the problem clearly: `\` is a escape character and it's escaping the following character. `'` isn't interpreted as string end, but as a `'` character in that string. Then your string spans over to the next line, which is not allowed and PHP throws an error.

If you want to use `\` in strings, you need to type `\\` - the first one will escape the second one:

```
define ('DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\myapplicationname\\members\\');
define ('DB_LOG', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\myapplicationname\\members\\log\\db');
define ('ERROR_LOG', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\myapplicationname\\members\\log\\errors');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to escape all backslashes, because they are special characters in PHP:

```
define ('DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\myapplicationname\\members\\');
define ('DB_LOG', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\myapplicationname\\members\\log\\db');
define ('ERROR_LOG', 'c:\\wamp\www\\myapplicationname\\members\\log\\errors');
```

Comment: ouch.  that's a lot of work. just a question. is there any way I can leave the original paths with "/" as we use in linux and somehow have wamp figure it out?

Comment: @dot I think Mark Baker answered that in the comments to the question.